# Can I pull image from public repository without secret inside cloud?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Currently, I am pulling image from Object-Storage using a secret. This secret is stored in dockerconfigjson.

I want to replace object-storage with public Repo. And going forward, I will pull this image from public Repo inside my cloud tenancy.

[EDIT]

I can remove imagePullSecret from pod's yaml specification to pull image from public repo.

Do you see any flaw if I am not using secret to pull image?

Any suggestions?

Comment: As mentioned in provided answer, public repo and logged in users are not matching to each other. As well as you don't need any secrets/keys when access **public** repo. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 3):

Both statement looks different and mismatch

> I want to replace object-storage with public Repo. And going forward,
> I will pull this image from public Repo inside my cloud tenancy.
>
> User cannot pull this image if they are not logged-in in cloud
> tenancy.

If it's public there should not be any type of **Auth Z/N** required.

When you say public repo

> So can I remove imagePullSecret from pod's yaml specification?

yes you can remove the **imagePullSecret**